# Sign in with Yammer is using 'http' instead of 'https' so fails with 'Invalid Redirect URI' error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, yammer

Yammer login works correctly when I am logging in using my own Yammer account for our network. Whenever I use anyone else in our network I get an 'invalid redirect uri' error. Is there a reason why it would only work when I am logging in and not other people? Would the redirect uri error be purely Yammer server side related?

Comment: Ok so I have finally nailed down the issue. The redirect URI does not contain the 's' in 'https' despite the redirect call back uri in the 'created apps' section of Yammer being completed correctly.

This is copied directly from the callback URI url when the callback occurs 'redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F'. In the 'created apps' section my expected redirect is written as 'https://example.com/users/auth/yammer/callback'.

Is there a reason why Yammer would redirect the user to a 'http' callback uri instead of the 'https' version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had everything set up correctly in the Yammer created apps but I was visiting my production url using `http` instead of `https`. This was then overriding the redirect uri. I could fix this by changing the url on the `invalid redirect_uri` page to include the `s` and it would redirect correctly.

Seems like a bug that the source url would override the `http` part of the Yammer Created Apps `redirect uri`.